# Bootstrap datepicker is not working + cakephp 2.0.3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.3, datepicker

I am trying to implement the datepicker from [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) 
copied all the files to the js and css folder as accordingly and trying to call the datepicker on this page but it doesn't shows up.
here is the code of the page:

```
    <?php 
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.9.1.js');
echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.js');
echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap-datepicker.js');

echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.css');
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-responsive.css');
echo $this->Html->css('datepicker.css');

?>
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('full_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email', array('readonly' => true));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('zip');
        echo $this->Form->input('gender', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => array('male' => 'M', 'female' => 'F'), 
                 'legend' => false, 'value' =>  isset($this->data['User']['gender']) ? $this->data['User']['gender'] : 'male'));
        echo $this->Form->input('birthday', array('class' => 'datepicker', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => false));


    ?></fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'));?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

//-->
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Should it not be `$('.datepicker').datepicker(...`?

Comment: What is the possible solution then?

Comment: As I said - replace `$('#datepicker')` with `$('.datepicker')`. Did this work?

Comment: no I tried this also it didn't worked out.I found out the real problem the bootstrap.css is overridden by another css. will you please tell me how to stop a css to overide another css??

Comment: You should include the bootstrap.css file last.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    });
});
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    });
});
```

Your use css class as a selector, not the DOM ID.

Answer (score 0):

Download The Bootstrap Datepicker tool From
[http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker][1]

Add The CSS File In the Layout

Html->script('jquery.js') ?>
    Html->script('bootstrap-datepicker.js') ?>

In Your View:

Form->input('dob',array('id' => 'dp1'));?>

Add Addition Script:

$(function(){
            window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
            $('#dp1').datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
            });

        });

Thank you